# Lilypond- Half diminished Seventh symbol

Tags: lilypond

I'd like to write notes with explicit chord notation.
I have

> \set majorSevenSymbol =  \markup { \super "maj9" }

Which works just fine, so was trying to guess something similar like:

> \set halfDiminishedSevenSymbol = \markup { \super "m7b9" }

But didn't find a variation that makes it work. Any suggestion appreciated, and also any suggestion to a more systematic approach for finding relevant handles... Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You couldn't find a variation that would make it work because it seems that there is none. The complete list of options related to the chord naming should be on this page in docs: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/displaying-chords .

It looks like you will need to set the `chordNameExceptions`. There is a [snippet](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/snippets/chords#chords-chord-name-exceptions) in the snippet list that does a similar thing and that you will probably be able to easily adapt to whatever you need. Have a look at this [lilybin](http://lilybin.com/hojo2y/1) (a web app that compiles and renders Lilypond snippets).

(By the way, I'm not sure why you set the major 7 symbol to maj9 and want to set the half diminished symbol to m7b9. If you want the 9th chords, then it will be far cleaner to write them as such, for instance with `d:maj9`. And if you use e. g. `c:m7.9-` for your m7b9, then an appropriate symbol will be used so you don't need to change anything.)

Comment: Thanks! Yes I read through the chord naming before I posted but thought there would be a more systematic approach. Anyway, now I use the chordNameExceptions as you suggest, and if it useful for anyone I think the way to make a nice exception is: '<c ees ges bes>2.-\markup { \super {"m7" \char  ##x266D "5"} }'